# PHPUnit - Running a particular test suite via the command line test runner

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Is it possible to specify which test suite to run from a configuration file via the command line test runner? For example, if I have the following xml configuration:

```
<phpunit ...>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="My Test Suite 1">
            <directory>./MyTestSuite1/</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="My Test Suite 2">
            <directory>./MyTestSuite2/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    ...
</phpunit>
```

Can I have it run only "My Test Suite 1"?

Comment: I know you can individual tests from Testcase. Not sure about suites though. Try to do something like `phpunit Suitename Path/To/AllSuites.php` or other way round. Also, check `phpunit --help` and http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/textui.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- you can use the @group tag in the class documentation to indicate the group and then run tests only on that group using --group
- you can use --filter to only run tests that match a given regex

Update 2013

As @havg's answer below mentions, it's now possible to run individual test suites using `phpunit --testsuite`

Comment: This works nicely and is probably the best bet if test suites cannot be run individually. Thanks!

Answer (score 57):

It's `phpunit --testsuite "My Test Suite 1"`

Comment: the --testsuite flag does not exist until 3.7

Comment: Note that there are reserved keywords, for example using "directory" as the test suite name will fail. `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Class "Directory" does not extend PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried when you run phpunit from the command line to add a path as a parameter?

So something like

```
 phpUnit ./MyTestSuite1/
```

?

Comment: This does work unless a test suite spans multiple directories that do not share the same root. Thanks.