# What is a testCase and a testSuite?

Tags: robotframework, testcase, test-suite

I am working with robotframework and I would like to know the definition of these 2 concepts. Both a TestCase and a TestSuite. I already looked in the documentation page but nothing comes as a definition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between test suite, test case and test category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069595/difference-between-test-suite-test-case-and-test-category)

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id498) says about a **test suite**:

> test suites are just files and directories that can be versioned with the production code.

More broadly, a test suite file is a collection of one or more test cases in a single file, and a test suite directory is a collection of other test suites.

A **test case** is a collection of one or more keyword invocations grouped together and given a name in a test case table. This is how they are briefly described in the [user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-case-syntax):

> Test cases are constructed in test case tables from the available keywords.